# How do you get all tenant IDs for AAD your user is part of?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

How do you use powershell to find all tenant IDs for all AADs your AAD user is part of? Similar to what you see when you login to `portal.azure.com` where without logging into each AAD you can see a list of directories your user account is part of in drop down like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you use powershell to find all tenant IDs for all AADs your AAD user is part of?

If we want to get all of tenant IDs, we could use the [Get-AzureRmTenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermtenant?view=azurermps-6.0.0).

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

Get-AzureRmTenant
```

[image]